# titanium classic android slide a view like facebook slide menu?

Tags: android, slider, titanium

I am building a titanium classic mobile project where I want a Facebook like slider menu, both for Android and **iOS**. In GitHub I have found projects which work great for iPhone but dont work with Android. I have been trying for weeks now but without much success.

I want a solution which works for both Android and iPhone. Can anyone share some information on the same.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good solution, NappDrawer Module works fine for android and iOS, and if you face a bug, you post it and most probably they help you or they fix it.

You're gonna have to use views for android and windows for iOS.

Here's the module's link [NappDrawer Module](https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer).

And this is the [documentation](https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer/tree/master/android).